# Find Overlapping Objects in Array and return only those overlapping

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": "line-23746045",
        "line_top": 543,
        "line_bottom": 521
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746033",
        "line_top": 132,
        "line_bottom": 110
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746031",
        "line_top": 138,
        "line_bottom": 116
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746029",
        "line_top": 143,
        "line_bottom": 121
    }
]
```

I need to return only those that are overlapping between line_top and line_bottom. in the array above, "line-23746045" is not overlapping, so I would like to return an array as such:

```
[
    {
        "id": "line-23746033",
        "line_top": 132,
        "line_bottom": 110
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746031",
        "line_top": 138,
        "line_bottom": 116
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746029",
        "line_top": 143,
        "line_bottom": 121
    }
]
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Just use nested loops that compare `line_top` and `line_bottom` between each pair of items. If they overlap, you add the items to the result array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A simple solution**

You can filter the array and collect intersections with the next items for each array item to avoid checking intersections with the previous items:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "line-23746045",
        "line_top": 543,
        "line_bottom": 521
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746033",
        "line_top": 132,
        "line_bottom": 110
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746031",
        "line_top": 138,
        "line_bottom": 116
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746029",
        "line_top": 143,
        "line_bottom": 121
    }
]

const intersected = new Set;
const intersect = (val, item) => val >= item.line_bottom && val <= item.line_top;
const result = arr.filter((item, idx, arr) => {
  let found = false;
  for(let i = idx + 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    const next = arr[i];
    if(intersect(item.line_bottom, next) || intersect(item.line_top, next)){
      intersected.add(next);
      found = true;
    }
  }
  return found || intersected.has(item);
});

console.log(result);
```

**A more complex and performant solution**

You could group the overlapping items and keep track of line_bottom and line_top of overlapped items and compare against them:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "line-23746045",
        "line_top": 543,
        "line_bottom": 521
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746033",
        "line_top": 132,
        "line_bottom": 110
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746031",
        "line_top": 138,
        "line_bottom": 116
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746045",
        "line_top": 580,
        "line_bottom": 530
    },
    {
        "id": "line-23746029",
        "line_top": 143,
        "line_bottom": 121
    }
]

const groups = [];
const intersected = new Map;
const intersect = (val, item) => val >= item.line_bottom && val <= item.line_top;

for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
  const item = arr[j];
  let found = false;
  const intersected = []; // collect intersected groups and merge them
  for(const group of groups){
    debugger;
    if(intersect(item.line_bottom, group) || intersect(item.line_top, group)){
      intersected.push(group);
    }
  }
  if(!intersected.length){
    groups.push({line_bottom: item.line_bottom, line_top: item.line_top, items: [item]});
  } else {
    // merge groups
    const first = intersected[0];
    let min = first.line_bottom, max = first.line_top;
    for(let i = 1; i < intersected.length; i++){
      const group = intersected[i];
      first.items.push(...group.items);
      if(min > group.line_bottom) min = group.line_bottom;
      if(max < group.line_top) max = group.line_top;
      groups.splice(groups.indexOf(group), 1);
    }
    if(min > item.line_bottom) min = item.line_bottom;
    if(max < item.line_top) max = item.line_top;
    first.line_bottom = min;
    first.line_top = max;
    first.items.push(item);
  }
}

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ max-height: 100% !important}
```

Comment: What if I have different intersecting elements on different line_top and line_bottom, for example: I f I have another object that intersects with another line, how would I be able to group them so the function returns different groups of intersecting lines in different line_top and line_bottom "regions" ?

Comment: @MrIsoMan added the grouping though the code is more complex